# Removing a file from a docker container

Tags: docker

It's quite simple but I don't have any explanation why this is not working:

In my Dockerfile:

```
RUN rm -rf /etc/nginx/sites-*/*
```

Once built and run, inside the container the files are still there:

```
ls -lrth /etc/nginx/sites-*/*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.1K Jan 26 23:34 /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   34 Apr 21 15:58 /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  691 Apr 21 16:12 /etc/nginx/sites-available/default.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   39 Apr 21 16:17 /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.conf -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/default.conf
```

I can see in th build that the action was done:

```
Step 13 : RUN rm -rf /etc/nginx/sites-*/*
 ---> Running in 0fa2deabe45c
 ---> 33e7b85a6c05
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04.4

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/stable
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php

RUN add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get -y --force-yes install php7.0-fpm git php7.0-mysql php7.0-curl

RUN apt-get install --force-yes -y nginx

RUN rm -rf /etc/nginx/sites-*/*
```

Comment: Have you tried simply `rm -rf /etc/nginx/sites-*` to see whether it's something with the wildcards? Or are you specifically only after the `*/default` files/directories?

Comment: I tried inside the container. It works. From the Dockerfile it won't do it.

Comment: can you show your Dockerfile, a reproducer?

Comment: Can you show us the `docker build` output? It should tell you something when it gets to the `rm` line - did it fail with some error?

Comment: Inside the container you probably run `bash`, the Dockerfile's commands are executed using `sh`. This may be the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me as expected.

I started by putting setting up your Dockerfile locally:

```
$ mkdir dockertest
$ cd dockertest
$ cat > Dockerfile
<paste dockerfile here>
```

Then building the image:

```
$ docker build -t dockertest .
```

You can see the complete build process [here](https://asciinema.org/a/89mj3qc8kijefdqrmla8uazso).

Once the image is built, I can verify that those directories are empty:

```
bash-4.3$ docker run --rm dockertest ls -l /etc/nginx/sites-{available,enabled}/
/etc/nginx/sites-available/:
total 0

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/:
total 0
bash-4.3$
```

You'll note that I didn't use wildcards in the previous command.  If I had instead run this...

```
$ docker run --rm dockertest ls -l /etc/nginx/sites-*/*
```

...that would have listed files on my *host* filesystem, because shell wildcard expansion happens *before* the command runs.  You could do this safely by running:

```
$ docker run --rm dockertest sh -c 'ls -l /etc/nginx/sites-*/*'
```